# Javascript выборка radio:checked

Tags: javascript, input, radio

Есть несколько *input radio*, но только один *checked*, вот именно к нему нужно обратится с помощью Javascript.
В общем нужен аналог функции Jquery:

```
$(".item:radio:checked").click();
```

Comment: Чем `$("radio:checked").click();` не устраивает?

Comment: Она меня устраивала бы, но используется язык Javascript, поэтому нужен аналог на Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая вещь, как [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) - возвращает первый элемент внутри документа (используется предупорядоченный обход узлов в глубину до первого найденного узла), который совпадает с определенной группой селекторов.

Синтаксис

```
element = document.querySelector(selectors);
```

где

`element` — объект element.
`selectors` — строка, содержащая один или более CSS селекторов, разделённых запятой

```js
var checkedRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="rate"]:checked');
console.log(checkedRadio);
console.log(checkedRadio.value);
```

```html
<div id="rates">
  <input type="radio" id="r1" name="rate" value="Fixed Rate"> Fixed Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r2" name="rate" value="Variable Rate"> Variable Rate
  <input type="radio" id="r3" name="rate" value="Multi Rate" checked="checked"> Multi Rate  
</div>
```

еще вариант

```js
var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
  if (radios[i].checked) {
    console.log(radios[i].value);
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="male" checked>Male
<input type="radio" name="genderS" value="female">Female
```

Comment: Алексей спасибо! Первый вариант то что надо!